# Run a Python script when opening Terminal(xterm)

Tags: linux, gnome, xterm

Is there a way I can run a Python3 script while I open xterm?

**What I want to do:**
I want to create a ToDo list, which runs on startup of xterm (should be able to use ArgParse)

**OS**
I use gentoo = a unix/linux distro --> gnome3(X.org)

**My research**
I didn't find any solution, there were only results, where people wanted to start the Python interactive mode and not a solution to my problem (the way around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an alias, that is modify your .bashrc and add the next line:

```
my_alias='xterm -e /path/to/script/ /path/to/todo_script'
```

Where script file is the following [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/46640):

```
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
exec "$SHELL"
```

And todo_script is the script that you want to execute. For example, if todo_script contains

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
```

If you execute my_alias, it will show Hello World in a new xterm terminal.